How to get a DataFrame, separate it in to smaller segments and write those into a excel workbook in different worksheets
I have this big data base that I need to separate into diferent segments (diferent "valid until dates") and then get each o the segments into a excel workbook. Each of the segments also should have its own excelsheet.
Df Exemple:
            A                   valid until                       C                D 
Date                                                                        
01/08/2023  Tesouro Educa+      15/12/2030              5,06             5,18   
02/08/2023  Tesouro Educa+      15/12/2030              5,05             5,17   
03/08/2023  Tesouro Educa+      15/12/2030              5,02             5,14   
04/08/2023  Tesouro IPCA+       15/12/2030              5,02             5,14   
07/08/2023  Tesouro IPCA+       15/12/2030              4,98             5,10   
...
01/08/2023  Tesouro Selic       15/12/2031              5,05             5,17   
02/08/2023  Tesouro Selic       15/12/2031              5,03             5,15   
03/08/2023  Tesouro Educa+      15/12/2031              5,00             5,12   
04/08/2023  Tesouro Educa+      15/12/2031              5,02             5,14   
07/08/2023  Tesouro Educa+      15/12/2031              4,99             5,11  

What i tried:
df = pd.read_csv(r'PATH', sep=';')
df.sort_values(by=['valid until','Date'], key=lambda x: np.argsort(natsorted(dados['Date'])))

valid_until_list=dados['valid until'].unique()

for i in valid_until_list:
    df2=df[(df['Date']==f'{i}')]
    df2=df2.set_index(['Data Base'])

    with pd.ExcelWriter(r'NEW_PATH',engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists='replace', mode='a') as writer:
        i=i.replace('/','_')
        
# Here i tried changing the name of the worksheets:
        sheet_title=''
        if df2['A']=='Tesouro IPCA+ com Juros Semestrais':
            sheet_title='IPCA+ Juros'
        elif nova_df2['A']=='Tesouro IPCA+':
            sheet_title='IPCA+'
        else:
            sheet_title=''


        df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'{sheet_title}_{i}')`

The code did work until i tried to change de worksheet title, now is showing this: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
I'm here to ask 2 things. My df is kinda big (145712 rows), so de code is taking way to long to run. Is there a faster way to do this, maybe without using for and if loops? The second would be: how do i fix this title Error? It is not necessary, but would make my life soooo much easier :))

You can use groupbyto form the DFs and write them directly to sheets; the code below defines groups according to 'valid until' and then sorts each group (ie sub-DF) according to the Date column.
groupings = df.groupby('valid until')

count = 1
with pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", mode = 'w') as writer:
    for g in groupings:
        sheetname = 'sheet'+str(count)
        g[1].sort_values(by = 'Date').to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname, index=False)
        count += 1

This gives sheet1, sheet2 etc but you can change to sheet name formation as required. The 'valid until' of each DF is g[0] in the above code if that is useful.
If it is required to form the groups (and so sub-DFs) using both 'valid until' and 'Date' then the grouping statement would be changed to groupings = df.groupby(['valid until', 'Date']) and the sort expression then omitted from the statement in the for loop.
The same general principle could be use to form sub-DFs using any combination of the columns.

Thank you for the sugestion. It would need to be sorted by Date (when it was published) and by valid_until (when will expire the validation).

Do you mean sort the order by Date within 'segment' defined only by valid until or use both valid until and Date to define the 'segments' for the separate DFs? See edited answer which covers both these approaches. If this is not what you want please clarify and I'll adjust the answer. The best way is to use groupby to form groups which are configured however you want; this is preferable to using a loop to form the sub-DFs.
